# How to import select2 and jquery in separate file in webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am working in laravel project. I have imported `jquery` in `app.js` file and `select2` in `form.js` file.

But this not worked. It gives the error  `$(...).select2 is not a function`.

But if I import them on same file it works fine.

I have imported them on different file because jquery will be used in all web pages but select2 will be used in specific page. So to load minimum js I have kept them in different files.

So please guide me how can I import `select2` and `jquery` in separate file in webpack.